# How do I put my button on the same line as my Component Title?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

how can I modify my Title.jsx code in order to have the possibility to give to this component another component i.e a button inside my Title component ?
Because if I want to display a button in the same line (on the right) as my title it's not possible, it's displayed under it (see picture). So do I have to go through this way or just using tailwindcss (which is not working if do right-0 left-0) ??

```
export default function Title({ className, title, children }) {
    return (
        <Format className={className}>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <hr />
            {children}
        </Format>
    )
}

export default function Format({ className, children }) {
    return (
        <div className={`${className ?? ''}`}>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Display() {
return (
   <Title>
     <button> Button </button>
   </Title>
}
```

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lewin-ejrdgj?)

Here the picture:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to change order and encapsulate items inside Title's component:

```js
export default function Title({ className, title, children }) {
    return (
        <Format className={className}>
            <Format className="flex">
                <h1 className="flex-1">{title}</h1>
                {children}
            <Format/>
            <hr/>
        </Format>
    )
}
```

And add `className` what you want for new div wrapper, for example, `flex` and `h1` title with `flex-1` to expand it. If children is null, title will expand fullWidth.

I've updated answer and assume you will use div wrapper with Format component.

[Guide in tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex)

Comment: Hi, wow it's moving all the content of my page, everything is in a mess, is there another way ?

Comment: Please, could you share a codesandbox to test it?

Comment: Yes I've edited my question by adding the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lewin-ejrdgj?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flex`  property to achieve the same layout that you want. The idea is to keep the `Title` and `Button` in the same `div` with each of them are also enclosed within their separate `div` or `span`. And add `flex justify-between items-center` in the main div.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="p-4 flex items-center bg-slate-200 justify-between">
  <div><h4 class="font-semibold"> My Title</h3></div>
  <div><button class="bg-purple-700 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-md">Click</div>
</div>
```